# banner layout xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, adbannerview

I have this problem on all my apps, randomly when i start the app the banner will put all the items from this position:
[image: 1-]

To this position:
[image: 2-]

and all the items seem straslate up. Someone can help me to fix that bug? There are some code error/constrains error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add contraints to the banner but it will become distorted in other devices so I would not recommend this.

I suggest you constrain the elements to each other and to the sides of the app so they come together properly and this should force the banner to another position. Hope this helps.